# Regex MIGHT start with SE

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that will compare a code that MIGHT start with SE but does not have to. Examples:

XXXXX

XXX-XX

XXX XX

SEXXXXX

SEXXX-XX

SEXXX XX

SE XXXXX

SE XXX-XX

SE XXX XX

What I have so far is: /^(s?e?)(\s?)(\d{3})(\s|-?)(\d{2})$/i;

but the problem with that is that it can start with only s or only e. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s?e?` part will check for either `s` or `e`.

Try the following instead:

```
/^(?:se)? ?\d{3}[- ]?\d{2}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write
 /^(SE\s){0,1}(\d{3})(\s|-?)(\d{2})$/i

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it looks fine, if I understand your requirements. The `s?e?` part will allow it to start with `SE` *or* only `S` *or* only `E`, which sounds like what you want. But you don't need most of those parentheses unless you're trying to separate the different segments of the code into capture groups. Also, this looks incorrect: `(\s|-?)` I think it will still work if there's neither `\s` nor `-` there, but it's an awkward way of writing it.

I think this should work fine:

```
/^s?e?\s?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{2}$/i
```

If you DON'T want it to start with only `S`, only `E`, or whitespace, then use this:

```
/^(se\s?)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{2}$/i
```

Comment: The problem wasn't the parantheses, it was (as VisioN said) s?e? checks for both, which was not working.

Comment: @MaGi - I wasn't sure if you wanted to allow only S/only E. If you don't, the second pattern is what you need. The problem was definitely not the parentheses, that was just an incidental suggestion.